# implementing a threads package in user space

Tags: c, multithreading

So is it possible to implement a threads package in user space while the operating system does not have anything like the select system call to see in advance if it is safe to read from a file, pipe, or device, but it does allow alarm clocks to be set that interrupt blocked system calls?

Comment: You seem to be mixing many different concepts. I will answer the the first question: You can implement green threads with cooperative scheduling, this means that you have multiple concurrent code paths that the *real* thread switches to one at a time, they have to explicitly release control. For everything else (running the code really in parallel and without the explicit release, ...) you need help from the OS.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/pth/